# [es painless]difference between doc and params._source

Tags: elasticsearch-painless

when use doc["abc"],it turns out no field "abc" exception, only to find params._source["abc"] get everything correct.

I checked the status of doc["abc"].value ,it shows null , also doc["abc"].empty is true.

1.elasticsearch version:5.x

2.use painless inline sort script

can anybody figureit out what. happened?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on where a script is used, it will have access to certain special variables and document fields. I dont know your mapping, but i think this link will answer your questions - [Accessing document fields and special variables](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/modules-scripting-fields.html#modules-scripting-fields)

To quote further from above link:

> **Doc values and text fields**
>
> The doc['field'] syntax can also be used for analyzed text fields if
>   fielddata is enabled, but BEWARE: enabling fielddata on a text field
>   requires loading all of the terms into the JVM heap, which can be very
>   expensive both in terms of memory and CPU. It seldom makes sense to
>   access text fields from scripts.
>
> *Doc values are a columnar field value store, enabled by default on all
>   fields except for analyzed text fields.*
>
> The **_source** provides access to the original document body that was
>   indexed (including the ability to distinguish null values from empty
>   fields, single-value arrays from plain scalars, etc).

if your field `abc` is an analyzed text field or an object, `doc` wont work.

Comment: Hi @Polynomial Proton, I was trying to access "_source" field using painless script but getting error.

If you could check my query my it would be helpful.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72803840/access-nested-objects-using-painless-for-elasticsearch-opensearch-alerting-to-cr